# Row is getting duplicated in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My column is duplicating and I don't understand why. It doesn't happen to the columns that don't have the class applied to them.

What can I do?

```
<tr v-for="(item, key) in array.filter(el => el.Id !== null)">
  <td>@{{ key + 1 }}.</td>
  <td>
    <div 
      v-for="subitem in array.filter(el => el.Id === item.Id)" 
      v-bind:class="array.filter(el => el.Id === item.Id).length > 1 ? 'children-row' : ''"
    >
      @{{ subitem.NAME }}
      <span">
        <i> edit </i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    @{{ item.NAME2 }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is the array

```
Name: "John", Id: 10, NAME2: "Joey", IdParent: 16 
Name: "Mike", Id: 11, NAME2: "Mark", IdParent: 19 
Name: "Andrew", Id: 13, NAME2: "Mark", IdParent: 19
```

And this is the *.children-row* class style

```
.children-row {
     padding-top: 6px;
}
.children-row:nth-child(odd) {
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 6px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

**What i'm looking for is to have the objects which have the same Id, be grouped into the same table cell.**

This is what i currently have, the problem is that the second row, shows up twice

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLR7u.png)

Comment: Can you provide us with the complete code for this Vue component?

Comment: @TymoteuszLao i don't see how it would be useful since i don't have any other vue in this table, only the one listed above

Comment: If you don't have any other code it won't work because there's no `array`. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's necessary for code questions. Unless you're able to answer your own question based only on the code you posted, it's safe to assume that all necessary information needs to be provided in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, what does the class _children-row_ looks like? And from what I can see you are applying it to columns, not rows.

Comment: @EstusFlask This is the array
Name: "John", Id: 10, NAME2: "Joey", IdParent: 16
Name: "Mike", Id: 11, NAME2: "Mark", IdParent: 19
Name: "Andrew", Id: 13, NAME2: "Mark", IdParent: 19

Comment: @TymoteuszLao this is the class: 

.children-row {
            padding-top: 6px;
        }
        .children-row:nth-child(odd) {
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 6px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        }

Comment: This all should be presented in the question, in the form of code that can reproduce the problem by users who read it. Currently I see no legitimate reasons for it to work the way you described. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking. It's crucial to get your problems solved on SO

Comment: @user19442824 Should the idPartner be used somewhere here or is it irrelevant for this case?

Comment: @TymoteuszLao it is used in a different part of the code, so it is irrelevant here

Comment: @user19442824 I added a snippet to my answer can you check if this is similar to what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TymoteuszLao it's similar, but i posted a picture with my problem

Comment: @user19442824 I updated the solution in my answer, let me know if this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
<div 
  v-for="subitem in array.filter(el => el.Id === item.Id &&)" 
  v-bind:class="array.filter(el => el.Id === item.Id).length > 1 ? 'children-row' : ''"
>
```

The **div** component with its content will be generated as many times as many there are items with the same Id (because of v-for directive). For those columns, you will also apply the *children-row* class because this is the case where (...).lenght will be bigger than one. (That's why you can see that all duplicated columns have *children-row* applied)

If you change the first v-for directive to iterate only on the rows with unique Id you should get rid of duplicate rows

```
<tr v-for="(item, key) in array.filter((el, index, self) => el.Id !== null && index === self.findIndex((e) => (e.Id === el.Id))" >
```

Comment: and how can i fix that?

Comment: @user19442824 I added solution to my coment

Comment: when i remove that v-for, the code does work correctly and the class gets applied to the div, but it puts them in different rows

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve or present the desired outcome (based on the data you provide us with), so we can have a more clear perspective of your problem?

Comment: added it on my post